# Show/Hide Fragment instead of replace

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have 3 and more fragments and I want to access them with the drawer.
So that when I click on "Profile" the current fragment(i.e. Home) should hide and "Profile" fragment should show and vice versa..
Right now its working with "replace fragment" but,
Instead of replace I want to show/hide them when I click on the drawer button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //my coding
    

    replace(new HomeFragment());
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mDrawer = (FlowingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    iv_Menu = findViewById(R.id.iv_Menu);
    ll_Home = findViewById(R.id.ll_Home);
    ll_Profile = findViewById(R.id.ll_Profile);
    ll_Setting = findViewById(R.id.ll_Setting);
    ll_Share = findViewById(R.id.ll_Share);
    ll_Logout = findViewById(R.id.ll_Logout);

    iv_Menu.setOnClickListener(this);
    ll_Home.setOnClickListener(this);
    ll_Profile.setOnClickListener(this);
    ll_Setting.setOnClickListener(this);
    ll_Share.setOnClickListener(this);
    ll_Logout.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.iv_Menu:
            mDrawer.openMenu(true);
            break;

        case R.id.ll_Home:
            replace(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
            mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
            break;

        case R.id.ll_Profile:
            replace(new ProfileFragment(),"Profile");
            mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
            break;

        case R.id.ll_Setting:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SimplPreach.class));
            mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
            break;

        case R.id.ll_Share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Share.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
            break;

        case R.id.ll_Logout:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logout.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
            break;
    }
}

private void replace(Fragment fragment, String s) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fl_Main,fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(s);
    transaction.commit();
}

private void replace(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fl_Main,fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I have been searching from hours but nothing is working,
How can I use show hide instead of replace ..
Please help me..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction` has the following methods you can use.

```
show(Fragment fragment)
hide(Fragment fragment)
add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

And I think you don't need to call `transaction.addToBackStack(s)` in your case.

Comment: If you want to get current fragment you can use something like this.

public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
 return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragContainerId());
}

Comment: Hey Thanks for the Prompt response! I am a noob.. Sorry but I don't understand where should I use the above methods in my code.. Can you please help~ Thankyou~

Comment: Hey !! Somehow I figured it out~ It worked ~
Thanks again!